# Concatenate few rows into a single row with comma seperated using string_agg in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, string-agg

clique_bait.page_hierarchy

```
CREATE TABLE clique_bait.page_hierarchy (
  "page_id" INTEGER,
  "page_name" VARCHAR(14),
  "product_category" VARCHAR(9),
  "product_id" INTEGER
);
sample input 
  ('1', 'Home Page', null, null),
  ('2', 'All Products', null, null),
  ('3', 'Salmon', 'Fish', '1'),
  ('4', 'Kingfish', 'Fish', '2'),
  ('5', 'Tuna', 'Fish', '3'),
  ('6', 'Russian Caviar', 'Luxury', '4'),
  ('7', 'Black Truffle', 'Luxury', '5'),
```

clique_bait.events

```
CREATE TABLE clique_bait.events (
  "visit_id" VARCHAR(6),
  "cookie_id" VARCHAR(6),
  "page_id" INTEGER,
  "event_type" INTEGER,
  "sequence_number" INTEGER,
  "event_time" TIMESTAMP
);

sample input: 
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '1', '1', '1', '2020-02-04 19:16:09.182546'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '2', '1', '2', '2020-02-04 19:16:17.358191'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '6', '1', '3', '2020-02-04 19:16:58.454669'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '9', '1', '4', '2020-02-04 19:16:58.609142'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '9', '2', '5', '2020-02-04 19:17:51.72942'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '10', '1', '6', '2020-02-04 19:18:11.605815'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '10', '2', '7', '2020-02-04 19:19:10.570786'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '11', '1', '8', '2020-02-04 19:19:46.911728'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '11', '2', '9', '2020-02-04 19:20:45.27469'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '12', '1', '10', '2020-02-04 19:20:52.307244'),
  ('ccf365', 'c4ca42', '13', '3', '11', '2020-02-04 19:21:26.242563'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '1', '1', '1', '2020-01-18 23:40:54.761906'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '2', '1', '2', '2020-01-18 23:41:06.391027'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '4', '1', '3', '2020-01-18 23:42:02.213001'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '4', '2', '4', '2020-01-18 23:42:02.370046'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '5', '1', '5', '2020-01-18 23:42:44.717024'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '5', '2', '6', '2020-01-18 23:43:11.121855'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '7', '1', '7', '2020-01-18 23:43:25.806239'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '8', '1', '8', '2020-01-18 23:43:40.537995'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '8', '2', '9', '2020-01-18 23:44:14.026393'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '10', '1', '10', '2020-01-18 23:44:22.103768'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '10', '2', '11', '2020-01-18 23:45:00.004781'),
  ('d58cbd', 'c81e72', '12', '1', '12', '2020-01-18 23:45:38.186554')
```

clique_bait.event_identifier

```
CREATE TABLE clique_bait.event_identifier (
  "event_type" INTEGER,
  "event_name" VARCHAR(13)
);

Sample input
  ('1', 'Page View'),
  ('2', 'Add to Cart'),
  ('3', 'Purchase'),
  ('4', 'Ad Impression'),
  ('5', 'Ad Click');
```

The output i need is
Visit_id, Page_name which are added to cart concatenated with commas

my query

```
select visit_id, string_agg(page_name::character varying, ',') 
within group (order by sequence_number) as cart_items                        
from clique_bait.events e 
join clique_bait.page_hierarchy ph 
on e.page_id = ph.page_id 
join clique_bait.event_identifier ei 
on ei.event_type = e.event_type
where event_name = 'Add to Cart'
group by visit_id
```

is not working,  error: function string_agg(character varying, unknown, integer) does not exist

Comment: I noticed some questions you have asked in the past but never marked any of the answers as accepted. Were none of the answers to your previous questions acceptable?

Comment: I just did. Didn't know I should accept.

Comment: I’ve added an answer. If that’s what you are looking for and find the answer acceptable, you can mark it accepted so as to put closure to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
select visit_id, string_agg(page_name, ',' order by sequence_number) as cart_items                        
from events e 
join page_hierarchy ph on e.page_id = ph.page_id 
join event_identifier ei on ei.event_type = e.event_type
where event_name = 'Add to Cart'
group by visit_id
```

The `order by sequence_number` within the `string_agg(...)` function will sort your comma separated output based on sequence number.

Here's an example with the sample data you provided:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=52077d5be605a51d3a7bb14152a392df

Here're the results of that:

> ```
> visit_id | cart_items   
> :------- | :------------
> d58cbd   | Kingfish,Tuna
> ```